# why css flex and bootstrap not rendering when download the pdf in react js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying generating pdf of dynamic html which provided by backend response, I already downloaded pdf with below flow but unable to applying css flex, or bootstrap in pdf, Only margin, padding and web-kit flex css applying, so Any help is much appreciated.

I used pdf-creator-node in node js and first i saved pdf in backend directory, then passing pdf file name as response, which i just created using backend dynamic html file template and then called download api for get that pdf file as arrayBuffer/arrayBytes in react js. and then download the pdf using arrayBytes which getting from api response.

- Please consider reference images below which i tried.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

- Here, I created pdf using pdf.create() (pdf as pdf-creator-node - npm package)

[image: image 3]

- and I called download api along with fileName and download it.

[image: image 4]

- then, download api which return arrayBytes as response.